# Reviews analyze with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, adaboost

I am using scikit-learn to analyze an Amazon reviews dataset.
To achieve it (according with some examples) I do:

1. Change text and summary to lower case,
2. Change contractions and remove undesired characters
3. Create an `AdaBoostClassifier` to fit my model as follows

.

```
vect = CountVectorizer(min_df = 1)

ab = AdaBoostClassifier(learning_rate=0.1)
```

.

```
rnds = data_train.sample(frac = 1.0, random_state = np.random.RandomState(87824), axis = 0)

tests = data_test.sample(frac = 1.0, random_state = np.random.RandomState(824), axis = 0)

bow = vect.fit_transform(rnds['Text'])

ab.fit(bow, rnds['Score'])
```

When checking the accuracy for trained model with:

```
preds = ab.predict(vect.transform(tests['Text']))
print('Accuracy :' + str(100 * sum(preds == tests['Score'].values) / len(preds)) + '%')
```

I get about 70%.

My doubts are,

1. How could I improve this results? or is this the wrong way to do it?
2. `ab.fit` runs only once? I tried it into a `for` loop to check if accuracy increases, but the value is exactly the same over each iteration.

Thank you.

Comment: Some ideas: try using more training data in your train test split, maybe 80/20. Make sure to shuffle the dataframe before doing anything as well.  You can also try the ngram_range option in the CountVectorizer class init (set it to (1,2)). Finally, try another tool: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText  works quite well for supervised text classification and has nice python bindings. ab should also have a .score method, you can pass in your test inputs and values to.

Comment: yes, I split the dataset as you mentioned 80/20